Getting error om sam build - Error: PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies - {numexpr==2.10.1(wheel)}
Getting an error
Building codeuri: /home/sagemaker-user/lab4/rag_app runtime: python3.10 architecture: x86_64 functions: RagAppFunction                                                                                    
 Running PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies  

                                                                                                                                                                     

Build Failed
Error: PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies - {numexpr==2.10.1(wheel)}

Can someone help resolve this?
I have tried
pip install wheel
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
pip install numexpr==2.10.1
It did not work

Update Python 3.12.5.

Not really a solution but rather a workaround. You could build your function with PackageType: Image. In this case you have full control over building your own Image via Docker which is generally useful if you have a lot dependencies on system packages.
